# Parsing Data, Selecting data after and before certain characters

Tags: perl, scripting, shell

I am new to shell scripting and programming. I am looking for a guide on how I can parse specific information from a plain text file with thousands of lines. Specifically I need to parse an email address from each line. The line looks something like this:

```
"1272574001.H742765P10724.host.domain.com,S=4155:Return-path: `<email@email.com>`
```

I would like to extract the email address (excluding the `<` and `>`) and then perform an update statement via mysql with the email address as a value.

Is there an example of this somewhere that I could use to base my needs off of?

What scripting tool would I use, how do I tell that tool to grab all contents BETWEEN the `<` and `>`?

How do I then (within one script) use this value to update a DB record?

p.s. I am essentially trying to unsubscribe these email addresses from a contact database..

The SQL statement that needs to be run is:

```
UPDATE contact_master SET subscribed='No' WHERE email=<value>
```

Comment: What do you mean *excluding the $ and $*? What $ and $?

Comment: @Sinan: It's double the money.

Comment: I think he means the angle brackets around the email address. I guess he couldn't figure out how to escape them using Markdown.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for regular expressions.  I suggest reading the perlre manpage (available online [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)), then doing something like:

```
($addr) = /Return-path: `<([^>]+)>`/;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '`s/<\([^>]\+\)>`$/\1/' inputfile | while read -r address
do
    echo "UPDATE contact_master SET subscribed='No' WHERE email='$address'"
done | mysql databasename
```